# Mongoose query: remove "_id" attribute, keep virtual attribute "id" in results

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am running an Express.js app, and I have the following setup:

**models.js**

```
var schemaOptions = {
    toJSON: {
      virtuals: true
    },
    toObject: {
        virtuals: true
    }
};

var modelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name     : { type: String, required: true }

}, schemaOptions);

modelSchema.virtual('id').get(function() { return this._id; });
```

**controllers.js**

```
exports.getModel = function(req, res) {
    Model.find().select('name').exec(function(err,model) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({errors:err, message: 'Internal server error'});
        }
        return res.status(200).json({model: model});
    });
};
```

The result of the above query would be something like:

```
{ "_id":"dakjdjkakda", "name":"MontyPython", "id":"dakjdjkakda" }
```

because of the Virtual attribute I defined in the modelSchema.

If I change the query select statement to:

```
Model.find().select('-_id name').exec(function(err,model) {}
```

The result would be:

```
{"name":"MontyPython", "id":null }
```

I believe this happens because the Virtual attribute points to the _id attribute.

My question is, how can remove the _id attribute in the query, but keep the id alias I created?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because field selection works on database level and virtual properties work program level. A workaround can be to return a new object with fields that you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that. MongoDB requires `_id` attribute to be present as per [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/).

Your option is to use virtual attribute as in your example and perhaps [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to hide the field in the query result.

Otherwise, your mongo driver, such as Mongoose, should be able to hide or rename the desired field or attribute.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using mongoose, you can handle it using the `toJSON` function.

```
new mongoose.Schema(yourSchema, {
  toJSON: { 
    transform: function(doc, ret) {
      ret.id = ret._id;
      delete ret._id;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You might use global approach. Try this one out:

```
mongoose.plugin((schema) => {
  schema.options.toJSON = {
    virtuals: true,
    versionKey: false,
    transform(doc, ret) {
      ret.id = ret._id;
      delete ret._id;
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: this is a neat approach, mongoose models are actually repositories and should always retrieve business model objects, so if you don't expect the _id property (that is tightly coupled with underlying db technology) the odm layers have to transform it. 

One question comes in my mind: how to deal with unit testing/tdd ? shoul i always preload an actual instance of mongoose and just stub model methods when i need it?

Answer (score 4):

You can add virtual field `id` like this as you got it right in your code:

```
modelSchema.virtual('id').get(function () {

    return this._id;
});
```

and then remove the actual `_id` using `toJSON`'s transform option:

```
modelSchema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true,
    transform: function(doc, ret) {
        delete ret._id;
    }
});
```

Setting `virtuals: true` will make sure that your virtual field, i.e. `id` will be serialized.

Comment: in mongoose 6.4 I can use the `id: true` schema option directly to set the virtual id.

Comment: In mongoose 6 or above if you add any virtual to the schema then id is included by default. So if not needed this id as it is similar to _id it can also be removed just by setting id: false to the schema options. I tested this in mongoose 6.8

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do it with a little help of lodash :)

Notice that you can hide whatever field you want just by setting the hide option

```js
customerSchema.set('toObject', {
  hide: '_id version passcodeHash',
  transform: (doc, ret, options) => _.omit(ret, options.hide.split(' ')),
})
```