# Mongoose getting random object from array without getting the "_id"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hello I am trying to get a random object from array with mongoose but I am getting the `_id` with it. I used:

```js
let user = Schema.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$Users"
  },
  {
    "$sample": {
      "size": 1
    },
    
  }
])
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    "Users": "805249193890676736",
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000")
  }
]
```

So I am trying to get only the Users object as an output to use the User ID, is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose query: remove "\_id" attribute, keep virtual attribute "id" in results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566841/mongoose-query-remove-id-attribute-keep-virtual-attribute-id-in-results)

Comment: No sorry, It's a different issue, I already checked it out before asking

Comment: What have you tried to remove the id? Maybe add it to your question, so we can check why it didn't work.

Comment: The thing is, you cannot use the `.select({ Users: 1, _id: 0 })` with `.aggregate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `$project` step:

```
let user = Schema.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$Users"},
  {$sample: {size: 1},
  {$project: {Users: 1, _id: 0}}  
  }
])
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been searching for, thank you very much!